# Can number of call from cProfile be trusted

Tags: python

I have been trying to convert some for loop list creations into list comprehensions.  I have found many tutorials that are ok for the simple cases, but for more complex cases  (I am thinking of cases with more that one for and/or more than one if) how can I tell if the comprehension does the same thing as the loops?  Is there a standard of Python similar to the standard for C?

A simplified example:  str(a) is a function that takes a string and
return a string.
strlist2 is a list of equal length strings

```
       strlist2=[]
       for x in strlist1:
           y=[str(x) for z in range(0,len(x)+1)]
           strlist2+=y
```

(note y is a list hence += rather than .append)

my first (wrong) attempt was

```
       i.  strlist2=[y for x in strlst1
               for z in range(0,len(x)+1) for y in str()]
```

I later hit on what I think is the correct answer

```
      ii.   strlst2=[str(x) for x in strlst1 for z in range(0,len(x)+1)]
```

The problem is, what does i mean.  I assume

```
          strlin2=[]
          for x in strlist1:
             for z in range (0.len(x)+1):
                   temp=str(x)
                   for y in temp:
                        strlist2.append(y)
```

but this would mean len(strlint1)(len(strlist1[0])+1) calls to str
which is not what cProfile is telling me.

Comment: *"str(a) is a function that takes a string and return a string"*.  Do you mean you've shadowed the Python builtin `str` with your own function?  If so, maybe choose a different name in case the shadowing causes any weirdness in the profile results.

Answer (score 1):

I trust Python that both forms are (roughly<sup>[1]</sup>) equivalent :

```py
# a convoluted way to generate the strings for the integers from 0 to 99
for x in range(10):
  for y in range(10):
    str(x*10+y)
```

and

```py
[str(x*10+y) for x in range(10) for y in range(10)]
```

From my experience, it is. But I never checked. Let's do it :

```py
>>> # The calls to `str` were not recorded for a strange reason,
>>> # so instead I create a dummy function that I will supply to the profiled code
>>> def foo(val): pass

>>> # I bump the value to 10000 so that it takes a few seconds to run,
>>> # so there is something to profile
>>> cProfile.runctx("for x in range(10000):\n\tfor y in range(10000):\n\t\tfoo(x*10000+y)",
                    globals={"foo": foo}, locals={})

         100000003 function calls in 17.188 seconds
   Ordered by: standard name
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
100000000    3.668    0.000    3.668    0.000 <input>:1(foo)
        1   13.520   13.520   17.188   17.188 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000   17.188   17.188 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

>>> cProfile.runctx("[foo(x*10000+y) for x in range(10000) for y in range(10000)]",
                    globals={"foo": foo}, locals={})

         100000004 function calls in 14.998 seconds
   Ordered by: standard name
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
100000000    3.530    0.000    3.530    0.000 <input>:1(foo)
        1   11.321   11.321   14.851   14.851 <string>:1(<listcomp>)
        1    0.147    0.147   14.998   14.998 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000   14.998   14.998 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Both `ncalls` for `foo` are exactly `100000000` ( = 10000*10000).

It matches the [specification for comprehension lists "displays"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) :

> The comprehension consists of a single expression followed by at least one `for` clause and zero or more for or `if` clauses. In this case, the elements of the new container are those that would be produced by considering each of the `for` or `if` clauses a block, nesting from left to right, and evaluating the expression to produce an element each time the innermost block is reached.

In other words : the effect of the comprehension is the same<sup>[1]</sup> as if the `for` had been nested in the same order, and each iteration of the inner loop added a new value. But as you can see, it is a bit faster though.

<sup>[1]<sub>: From [the same spec as before](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries), "the comprehension is executed in a separate implicitly nested scope. This ensures that names assigned to in the target list don’t “leak” into the enclosing scope". In other words, it means you can't access your `x` and `y` outside the comprehension.</sub></sup>

You did not provide an actual example or a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the alleged error of calls from cProfile. But you should trust it. I do.
From the [cProfile documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#introduction-to-the-profilers) :

> cProfile [...] provide deterministic profiling of Python programs

As opposed to [statistical profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Data_granularity_in_profiler_types) which rely on **sampling**, cProfile should return accurate call counts (just their duration is more biased than for statistical).

---

Sidenote : there are many beginners tutorials for Python, but rarely they implement complex behaviors, indeed. For this, you would normally look for actual "production" code (typically on GitHub, or on PIP).